# Ncurses ACS_BLOCK not the same as WACS_BLOCK?

Tags: ncurses

I switched over from `add_ch` to having to use `add_wch` which caused me to also have to change using the various `ACS_` special drawing characters to the `WCS_` version.   The problem I found is that the `WCS_` version is not a FULL block, but only a partial block whereas the `ACS_` is the proper FULL block.   Is there a way to fix that?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a ncurses bug.  They define `WCS_BLOCK` as `0x25AE` but that is the "Vertical Rectangle".   The correct definition should have been `0x2588` which is the "Full Block".  So you have to create your own `cchar_t` and use that.  Something like:

```
wchar_t wch[2];
wch[0]=(wchar_t) 0x2588;
wch[1]=0;
cchar_t cch;
setcchar(&cch, wch, WA_NORMAL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: that is the answer.  whoever down voted doesn't know what they are talking about.

Comment: Hi what library were you using for the `cchar_t` and the `setcchar` ?